# which format for month plus year R requires in csv file to show it on x-axis in ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am trying to create a heat map showing data per month for 2 years, with Months on X axis and districts on y axis where as number as "fill".

My data is

```
Month        District          Number
Jan-17       Lahore            10
Feb-17       Lahore            15
Mar-17       Lahore            2
Apr-17       Lahore            7
May-17       Lahore            8
Jun-17       Lahore            9
Jul-17       Lahore            20
Aug-17       Lahore            13
Sep-17       Lahore            22
Oct-17       Lahore            14
Nov-17       Lahore            5
Dec-17       Lahore            5
Jan-18       Lahore            19
Feb-18       Lahore            21
Mar-18       Lahore            2
Apr-18       Lahore            17
May-18       Lahore            18
Jun-18       Lahore            12
Jul-18       Lahore            9
Aug-18       Lahore            1
Sep-18       Lahore            1
Oct-18       Lahore            1
```

The data is just showing one district/City. In my data i have 6 districts.The command i used is:

```
ggplot(HEAT_MAP2, aes(x = Month, y = District, fill = Number)) +
  geom_tile() +
  scale_x_date(date_labels = "%b%Y") +
  scale_fill_gradient(low = "white", high = "darkgreen", name = "Your Legend")
```

But it's giving error

> Error: Discrete value supplied to continuous scale

How can I remove this error to achieve the graph i am looking for.
Your help will be highly appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a common problem: the issue is that Month + Year is not a date. A date requires day, month and year.

The simplest solution is to add the first day of each month, so as `Month` can be converted to a date. Something like this:

```
library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)

HEAT_MAP2 %>% 
  mutate(Date = as.Date(paste0("01-", Month), "%d-%b-%y")) %>% 
  ggplot(aes(x = Date, y = District, fill = Number)) +
    geom_tile() +
    scale_x_date(date_labels = "%b%Y") +
    scale_fill_gradient(low = "white", high = "darkgreen", name = "Your Legend")
```

Comment: You're welcome; if the answer solves your problem please vote for and accept it.

Comment: @neilfws...i tried your above command now it is giving error: Error: Discrete value supplied to continuous scale
In addition: Warning messages:
1: In min(x) : no non-missing arguments to min; returning Inf
2: In max(x) : no non-missing arguments to max; returning -Inf
3: In min(diff(sort(x))) : no non-missing arguments to min; returning Inf

Comment: how can i remove this error. What wrong i have did?

Comment: In excel i selected the date format "date-month-year e.g. 14-Mar-2001

Comment: Code works with the example data from your question. Not sure why Excel is now involved, I'd stay away from that :)

Comment: No i am applying code to the data in cvs.format so my question is that is the selection of date from format cell option in excel affecting the outcome in ggplot2